# compare 2 date fields in joomla controller

Tags: php, joomla

i need to check 2 input form date fields in Joomla before saving a record and output a message to the user if the second date is greater than the first, without saving the record. I do not wish to do this check in JavaScript but in php. Also I do not wish to use the validate rules suggested by Joomla documentation. I want to do this in the sub-controller which handles the edit view.
Can you please help?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some of your code or let us know what you approach has been so we can help guide you.

Comment: I have tried JavaScript which has some validation, gives an alert if (date2>date1) but still saves the record. I also tried the validate rules but i found it extremely complicated. I am new at Joomla. I know the controller is the place to add your code, that is why i asked information on that. I have no code to show. Only an empty class that extends JControllerForm.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put dates to JDATE and do IF ($jdate > $jdate2)